# Is it possible to reference a cell in Microsoft Excel using the intersect of two named ranges?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a spreadsheet I'm making for my Thermodynamics class, I created an appendix with important values for certain molecules, such as the molar mass of Ethane. I have named the rows to the molecule names and columns to the important variables.

I want to be able to simply type some version of =Ethane_molarmass or something like that to call the specific cell. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have named the column `molarmass` and the row `ethane`, you can simply get the intersecting value using this formula:

```
=ethane molarmass
```

[image: Getting the intersecting value using a named row and named column]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=INTERSECT(ColumnRangeName, RowRangeName)
```

or without the named ranges, for example,

```
=INTERSECT(B:B,2:2)  for the value in Col B, Row 2
```

or dynamically (not ideal):

```
=INTERSECT(INDIRECT("ColumnRangeName"),INDIRECT("RowRangeName"))
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I do not find an `INTERSECT` function in Excel. Are you confusing it with the `Application.Intersect` method in VBA?

Comment: works for me (O365 v2102),  however i think your answer is better, never seen that before!

Comment: Strange, I do not find that function in v2201 and if I type it in, I get a `#NAME` error. I am always open to learn new things.

Comment: If I were to reference this on another sheet, would it be =Appendix!ethane mm ?